# How can i show a second XML DOM element with show more button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, dom, innerhtml

A page loads and a link loads the first element of an XML file.

```
txt = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("abstract")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = txt ;
```

I would like to add a button or a link that will load the second element XML element while keeping the first element in the div 'main'

i have tried to append a button;

```
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = txt + 
"<button onclick=\"alert()\">Click me</button>";
```

this will call an alert function fine.

is there any way I can use this function to call the second XML DOM element to the main div ?

Comment: are you willing to use jquery

Comment: yes i would but i am tied to the XML DOM approach